# How to check if lazy loading imge is complete in didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I use the following line to lazy load my images in cellForRowAtIndexPath...custom cell.

```
 [cell.picImageView sd_setImageWithURL:bkgUrl placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"holder_image_plain.png"]];
 [cell.profileImageView sd_setImageWithURL:proUrl placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"launch_120.png"]];
```

//
I then check if the image has changed from placeholder to user Image when the user clicks on custom cell with this in didSelectRowAt...

```
if([cell.profileImageView.image isEqual:[UIImage imageNamed:@"launch_120.png"]] && [cell.profileImageView.image isEqual:[UIImage imageNamed:@"launch_120.png"]]){
    NSLog(@"NOT yet...imge dl not complete");
}else{
    NSLog(@"All clear....go to detail page");
```

this has resulted in inconsistent results.  I assume it is because the display is showing more than one cell.  So I would like to know how or if I can specify to check the selected cell image has changed over ?  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this flow you are making the view responsible for keeping track of state. You should probably have your model keep track of when you should/shouldn't proceed to the next page.

You can do this by working with one of the methods that takes a completion handler. You could then update your model as appropriate in the completion handler and then your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` will be asking the model rather than the view for what it should do next

I've not used this library before but this should give you something to start with

```
__weak UIImageView *weakImageView = cell.profileImageView;

[cell.profileImageView sd_setImageWithURL:proUrl 
                         placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"launch_120.png"]
                                completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, NSURL *imageURL) {
                                  if (image) {
                                    // Update model to say that the image was downloaded

                                    weakImageView.image = image;
                                    [weakImageView setNeedsLayout];
                                  }
                                }];
```

Comment: Any hints on how to start the code it's self ?  not sure what a completion handler looks like ?  I will check The Almighty Google Gods...Thx for the help.